# Formatting Date in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Related to neo4j
I have a date object like "02-02-2012" {This is not a string type}. It is in date format. I want to get the answer as "02-Feb-2012". I have a way to do this in this format.

MATCH (var:`XYZ`) 
RETURN DISTINCT var.name, ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"][var.dob.month-1] + "-" + toString(var.dob.year) +  "-" + toString( var.dob.day)

Default date output of neo4j:- 02-02-1997
Obtaining Output: feb-1997-02

But I want to know is there any better way to do this?
Is there a way to reduce query length
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `APOC` there are some functions for formatting temporal values.
You can take a look at the documentation here : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_formatting_temporal_types

So your query should be :

```
MATCH (var:XYZ) 
RETURN DISTINCT var.name, apoc.temporal.format( var.dob, 'MMM-YYYY-dd')
```